# referencing an amd module(arcgis) in webpack app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm building a react app with webpack and i need to incorporate [arcgis maps](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) into a react component. I have know idea how to bring this into my project. I've tried creating an `arcgis` directory with an index.js of the built javascript and trying to reference that:

```
import {Map} from 'arcgis/index'
```

That doesn't work. I then just tried to include the css/js script tags directly into my `index.html` but when I try to `require` them, like in the example, webpack obviously can't find them. Is there some way to tell webpack to ignore `require` calls in my src file so it gets handled by the browser? I'm trying and failing at doing the following:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class EsriMap extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const _this = this

        require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
          var map = new Map(_this.refs.map, {
            center: [-118, 34.5],
            zoom: 8,
            basemap: "topo"
          });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="map"></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What does webpack do with this inner require?  Maybe try dojo.require to trick webpack into ignoring it?

Comment: Do you have any insight yet?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this https://github.com/tomwayson/esri-webpack-babel  .

This method is nice because it doesn't bog down the build.  You pull in the ESRI Api from the CDN, and tell webpack that it's an external.

```
//Add this...
externals: [
 // Excludes any esri or dojo modules from the bundle.
 // These are included in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, 
 // and its Dojo loader will pull them from its own build output
  function (context, request, callback) {
    if (/^dojo/.test(request) ||
        /^dojox/.test(request) ||
        /^dijit/.test(request) ||
        /^esri/.test(request)
    ) {
      return callback(null, "amd " + request);
    }
    callback();
  }
],
//And this to you output config
output: {
  libraryTarget: "amd"
},
```

When your app loads you bootstrap you webpack modules using Dojo in a script tag.

```
<!-- 1. Configure and load ESRI libraries -->
<script>
    window.dojoConfig = {
        async: true
    };
</script>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/"></script>

<!-- Load webpack bundles-->
<script>
    require(["Angular/dist/polyfills.bundle.js", "Angular/dist/vendor.bundle.js", "Angular/dist/app.bundle.js"], function (polyfills, vendor, main) { });
</script>
```

I've got it working with an Angular 2 App I'm working on.  The only downside is I haven't yet got the unit tests to run right using Karma.  I've only been working on that a few hours now.. Hope to have a solution to the testing issue soon.

Answer (score 0):

@getfuzzy's answer will work well as long as you don't need to lazy load the ArcGIS API (say for example only on a `/map` route).

For that you will want to take the approach I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40924016/656010)

This [blog post](http://tomwayson.com/2016/11/27/using-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-in-applications-built-with-webpack/) explains why you need to use one of these two approaches and explains how they work as well as the pros/cons of each.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try using bower version of esrijsapi. [Doc link](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_bower_custom_builds.html)

Comment: You cannot use webpack to directly load modules from the bower distribution of the ArcGIS API. This [blog post](http://tomwayson.com/2016/11/27/using-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-in-applications-built-with-webpack/) explains why.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Great post! I will try your solutions in my projects.